# Javascript array problem: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

This script has been running over at waterbirds.org for years. Now it's broken for some reason. It throws a "Cannot read property 'src' of undefined" error and I've tracked it down to preLoad[j].src (first line of runSlideShow function) as the problem because I can put a image link address there and it works. Any idea what's causing the problem?

```
// Waterbird Society Theme for Wordpress
// Rotating image banner applet
//
// Usage:
//<body onLoad='rotate_banner(slideShowSpeed, "Image1.jpg", "Image2.jpg"...)'>



var slideShowSpeed;
var j = 0;
var p;
var preLoad = new Array();

function rotate_banner() {
    var args = rotate_banner.arguments;
    slideShowSpeed = Number(args[0]);
    p = args.length;
    for (i = 0; i < p-1; i++) {
        preLoad[i] = new Image();
        preLoad[i].src = args[i+1];
    }
    runSlideShow();
}

function runSlideShow() {
    document.images['SlideShow'].src = preLoad[j].src;
    j++;

    if (j > (preLoad.length - 1)) j = 0;

    t = setTimeout('runSlideShow()', slideShowSpeed*1000);
}
```

Comment: When you are debugging, is it populating preLoad with values? Can you get a count of the number of images it contains? If that array is empty, indexing it will cause the error.

Comment: Details... please "var" the i and t variables.

Comment: it is working fine in both Chrome and FF6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is alright with your code except for it is run globally so all `var` declarations create global variables.

The exact issue on waterbirds.org is that `j` variable is defined somewhere before and by the moment it comes to `preLoad[j]` `j` equals `96`, and `preload[96]` is really undefined.

Wrap your banner in anonymous self-executing function, for example, to make vars local, and you're done:

```
(function(){

var slideShowSpeed;
var j = 0;
var p;
var preLoad = new Array();

// to keep rotate_banner global, save it as a property of window object
window.rotate_banner = function() {
    var args = rotate_banner.arguments;
    slideShowSpeed = Number(args[0]);
    p = args.length;
    for (i = 0; i < p-1; i++) {
        preLoad[i] = new Image();
        preLoad[i].src = args[i+1];
    }
    runSlideShow();
}

function runSlideShow() {
    document.images['SlideShow'].src = preLoad[j].src;
    j++;

    if (j > (preLoad.length - 1)) j = 0;

    t = setTimeout('runSlideShow()', slideShowSpeed*1000);
}

})()
```

And remember: [global variables are evil!](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/06/01/global-domination/) =)

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! I did also need to make the other function global using the same method: `window.runSlideShow() = function() {` but now it works like a charm! I would love to upvote you, but apparently I can't until my reputation is at 15 or greater... sorry